# Error 503 trying to delete in mongodb using node and hosted in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

Using mongoose to connect to mongolab and hosted in heroku. Method get, post , put works perfectly but deleting is the "problem".

when i tried to delete. i got it first.

```
Request URL:https://---------.herokuapp.com/------/54b413c2647bec02001efdd0
Request Headers 
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin:null
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
```

After 30 seconds more or less i got this.

```
Remote Address:150.100.2.200:8080
Request URL:https://---------.herokuapp.com/------/54b413c2647bec02001efdd0
Request Method:DELETE
Status Code:503 Service Unavailable
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,es-419;q=0.6,es;q=0.4,fr;q=0.2
Host:-----.herokuapp.com
Origin:null
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:484
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 12 Jan 2015 20:36:33 GMT
Server:Cowboy
```

I have this. Showing me an error 503 but.. if i chek on mongolab webpage the item is already gone. When i tested it in my local machine everything works fine including delete method but using heroku i got this problem.

-CORS avaliable.

-These are 3 different ways that i tried to do obtaining the same result.

```
exports.deleteNotificacion = function(req, res) {
 var id = req.params.id;
   console.log(id);
Todo.findById(id,function(err,notificacion){
    notificacion.remove();
    notificacion.save();       
       }); }


exports.deleteNotificacion = function(req, res) {
   var id = req.params.id;
console.log(id);
Todo.findById(id,function(err,notificacion){

      notificacion.remove (function(err){
        if (!err) {
          res.send('');
          console.log('Removed');
        }else {
          console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
        };
      })

    }); }


exports.deleteNotificacion = function(req, res) {
 var id = req.params.id;
console.log(id);
Todo.findByIdAndRemove(id,function(err){    
        if(err){console.log("ERROR " + err);}
           // res.send("eliminado");
           });}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code samples that you have posted are difficult to read, but it seems that you just don't send anything to the client if the request was successful. After 30s of waiting Heroku router timeouts and your client get a 503 page, as described [in this blogpost](http://artsy.github.io/blog/2012/11/15/how-to-monitor-503s-and-timeout-on-heroku/).

One of the correct responses to a DELETE request is to send HTTP 204 code with no body:

```
res.status(204).end();
```

Comment: Done! i wanted to recommend u but i couldn't cause i dont have enought points xD